# Time series forecast on Hourly Data in R

Tags: r, time-series, h2o, facebook-prophet

I have a CSV that has close to 2 months of data with data captured on an hourly basis.

The data set is as follows

```
Date_Time                    Freq
2018-06-01 01:00:00           232
2018-06-01 02:00:00           99
2018-06-01 03:00:00           90
```

Most time series examples mention this on yearly data. I am a bit lost with how to do forecasting on an hourly basis. What would be the best way to do it in R. There are many examples online that uses h2o, knn, ARIMA etc.

Comment: `Prohpet` is really easy to implement, and can handle hourly data: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#r-api, and here an example in Python https://www.kaggle.com/robikscube/tutorial-time-series-forecasting-with-prophet, which would be easy to translate in R.

Comment: This kind of questions are more suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/, since you ask which is the "best" way. You should find plenty of similar question there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # R
df <- read.csv('../examples/example_yosemite_temps.csv')
m <- prophet(df, changepoint.prior.scale=0.01)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 300, freq = 60 * 60)
fcst <- predict(m, future)
plot(m, fcst)
```

https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html